# Checking for incoming data type from file

Tags: c++, int, fstream

I'm reading in from a .txt file that looks something along the lines of:

```
int string string string
int string string
int string string string string string
```

where the number of `string` types after each `int` is unknown. Each line represents a new group of values and each group needs to be into their own array value or whatever (don't know if I've worded that correctly but I hope you'll understand what I mean).

Is there a check I can perform so see if the incoming data from the file is an `int` so that if this is true and can tell my program its a new group of data?

I've tried

```
int check
if(check = file1.peek()){//start new group assignment}
```

but this doesn't appear to work. I need to be able to use the `int` value once I have found that it is the next data type being read in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just check for newlines? If the next character is a newline consume it and read an int. Otherwise read a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, however I would suggest that maybe your groups are on separate lines, and the spaces within a line delimit items within a group correct?

So I would read the file, line-at-a-time and then split each line on spaces.

Let me know if the above fits and then we can explain how to do it.

Ok so you can use *getline*:

```
while (cin.good()) // reading from standard input until EOF
{
    String line_str;
    getline(cin, line_str); // get next line from standard input
    istringstream line(line_str); // put line into string stream

    if (line.good()) // read from string stream until EOF
    {
        int x;
        line >> x; // read an integer from string stream

        while (line.good()) // read from string stream until EOF
        {
            string s;
            line >> s; // read strings from string stream
            /// process s
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Each group is on it's own line with spaces separating the values within each line (they're actually not all strings but I should be able to work it out if we assume they are).

Comment: @user1331900: Okay, the above should do what you want.

Comment: Would you be able to comment the code a little? I'm slightly unsure what exactly is going on. If it helps, my function to import file looks like this so far: 
void fileinput(string datafile, record map){ 
 fstream file1(datafile);
while(!file1.eof()){....

Comment: @user1331900: ok, commented.  let me know if you need more.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort - this worked brilliantly! Just out of curiosity - what process would you suggest if I was to do it the way I originally planned?